# How to override setup values, like RSpec `let`, in shoulda contexts?

Tags: ruby, shoulda

Here's a nice technique I use with RSpec that I would also like to use in projects that use Shoulda and Shoulda-context. But I don't know if it's possible. Is there a way to do this?

What I want: define a `setup` (`before`) block in an outer context that references a `let` clause in a nested context. That way, inner contexts can configure values that are referenced in the outer `setup` And the `setup` can still be DRY across inner contexts.

RSpec example (this example is simple--please assume my real-life examples have a lot more code in the `before` block that I don't want to duplicate):

```
describe Thing do
  before do
    # Notice that `user` isn't defined here--it's defined in `let` blocks
    # in nested contexts below.
    login_as user

    # Assume there's lots more code here that I would like to keep
    # DRY across contexts.
  end

  context "when logged in as an admin" do
    # THIS IS THE MAGIC RIGHT HERE:
    let(:user) { Factory(:user, role: "admin") }

    it "should ..." ...
  end

  context "when logged in as a normal user" do
    # THIS IS THE MAGIC RIGHT HERE:
    let(:user) { Factory(:user) }

    it "should ..." ...
  end
end
```

To summarize: how can I do this with shoulda-context and Test::Unit?

Some things I have already tried that didn't work:

- `def` to redefine a method in each subcontext.
- `before_should` in each subcontext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found helper methods inside the test class useful for pulling out code repeated between tests.  Like this:

```
class MyTest < TestCase
  context "when logged in as an admin" do
    setup do
      do_login Factory(:user, role: "admin")
    end

    should "..." do
      ...@user...
    end
  end

  context "when logged in as an admin" do
    setup do
      do_login Factory(:user)
    end

    should "..." do
      ...@user...
    end
  end

  def do_login(user)
    login_as user
    @user = user

    # lots more setup code here...
  end
end
```